# Python: appending to a base class list/tuple member

Tags: python

I was asked this question a moment ago and couldn't think of a pythonic solution so I thought I'd throw it out here for a better viewpoint.

What is the best way to extend a base class variable tuple/list etc in a super class?

The following works...

```
class BaseClass(object):
    some_class_member = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,)


class AnotherClass(BaseClass):
    some_class_member = BaseClass.some_class_member + (6, 7,)

a = BaseClass()
a.some_class_member  # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

b = AnotherClass()
b.some_class_member  # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

But doesn't seem very pythonic as you have to reference the BaseClass by name so would have to update it if  the name changed. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: is it your intention for this tuple to be a static class object?

Comment: yes ideally, the class being extended is from a third party library

Comment: Is this Python 3 or no?

Comment: Why would a class name change in a third party library (not to mention that you still have to change it when inheriting)? More common case is that a field name changes. So first of all: I think that that's not a real life problem. And secondly: the code looks pythonic to me. Remember that in case of old-style classes you still have to reference the base class explicitely to use methods from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseClass` in `BaseClass.some_class_member` does not mean `super` of `AnotherClass`. It just

`BaseClass.some_class_member`. You can access without instantiation.

```
 >>> BaseClass.some_class_member
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If your purpose is to access the value without instantiation, the simple answer is `no`.
However, to access the value after instantiation.

How about?

```
class AnotherClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_class_member += (6, 7,)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm aware of how to access the member variable, it just seemed scrappy to me and I wondered if there was a better way. Taking advantage of `__init__` and setting it to an instance variable instead of a class variable may make it better in future

Answer (score 3):

I can kind of see your point, however, you're already referencing the `BaseClass` by name due to specifying it as a parent of your new subclass.

In the interest of the "what if the name changes" scenario, you could provide another layer of inheritance:

```
class MyBaseClass(BaseClass):
    """ This is here so that all of my classes just inherits from this one """


class AnotherClass(MyBaseClass):
    super_special_member = MyBaseClass.super_special_member + (6, 7, )


class ClassThatDoesntNeedSuperSpecialMember(MyBaseClass):
    """ Cool. """
```

`MyBaseClass` would act as a sort of "constant" variable in that you can change what it inherits from and everything else will automatically update.

Comment: Thanks, there may be a use for this down the line, on the surface though I agree with you that it seems like more work and maintenance to do it this way than the original way :)